# Bathroom faucet supply line quick connect uses pin. What is this called?

Tags: bathroom, faucet

The supply line that connects to the underside of the bathroom faucet uses a "quick connect" pin.

What is this type of connection called?

**More info:**
I am installing a water filter for the bathroom sink. The house was built using those cheap plastic all in one stop valves, so the supply line cannot be removed without replacing the stop valve also.

The problem I am encountering is the 1/2 end of the supply line that connects to the underside of the faucet uses a quick connect mechanism. One end simply "butts up against" the faucet threads and is held in place with a pin.

To simplify the replacement process, I want to buy a supply line with this type of "quick connect/disconnect", but I don't know the proper term to use when searching.

**EDIT**: After posting the pictures, I recall now why I didn't try to remove the "top" clamp. What is the purpose of that hose? There is one that comes from both the hot and cold supply line that meets in the middle.

[image: Quick Connect Supply Hose]

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea to use as a permanent water connection inside of a house.  This is for both ends.

Comment: Can you take a picture of the offending connection? (And for what it's worth, changing out an angle stop isn't hard and might improve your life in the future.)

Comment: Pictures, pictures!

Comment: There are virtually dozens of quick connects types out there. All called Quick Connect. **you can not be helped without photo**

Comment: Added some pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are called banjo connectors, the clip keeps the o ring sealed banjo fitting in place.

The banjo fittings were kind of expensive and really only used where space was a premium.

I doubt the big orange box stores will have them but a specialty plumbing and electric may stock them.

Comment: I'm happy to remove this connector and use the "standard" attachment method. However, the top of that connector has a line connected to it, so I stopped. I don't understand what the purpose is of this extra hose. (can be seen to the left in picture 1.) Do you know?

Comment: What is the second hose going to? It could be many things from a recirculating system to a bidet

Comment: For anyone who finds this in the future, I couldn't find banjo connectors ANYWHERE. What I did find, however, is that the banjo connector was actually an ADAPTER. Meaning, I simply unscrewed the banjo adapter from the cheap plastic piece and installed it on the new piece.

Comment: I just did a Google search for banjo water pipe fittings and found multiple matches, but they are also used on brake lines, but you wouldn’t use those for water.